# Query SQL database - one to many query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables (customer and reports). And they have a one to many relationship. I want to get one customer and all the reports which belong to this cusotmer. Here is the structure of my tables:

```
CUSTOMER:
+----+----------+-----+-----------+
| ID | Lastname | AGE | ADDRESS   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+

REPORT:
+----+-----------------+------+
| ID | Content         |state |
+----+-----------------+------+
|  1 | I am a content  |  ok  | 
|  1 | I am a content  |  ok  |
+----+----------+------+------+
```

So now i want to query my database for the customer Ramesh and get all his reports with the same ID. I want to show the reports in a table and the customer data in some textfields.

Is there a way to get all informations with one query or do i need more querys? One for customer and one for all reports?

Comment: `select * from Customer, Report where Report.ID = Customer.ID and Customer.ID = 1;`

Comment: Just a comment: Your database design needs fixing.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me what i can do better?

Comment: You need to provide a way to uniquely identify reports AND a way to relate reports to customers. This is basic stuff, and thoroughly covered by absolutely every beginners book or tutorial ever produced. It's disappointing that anyone or anything would see fit to upvote this.

Comment: In my original customer table i have one primary key its called adressnumber and in my reports table i have a column also called adressnumber, but there its not an primary field. So now every report has the adressnumber which belongs to one of the customers to identifie to which customer ist belongs. Is this a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your DB-Design needs to be revised. You could look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Its an explation about normalization of Databases.

In your case I would add a new column to your REPORT-table. You need this coulm to connect your to tables with each other and refer your reports to your coustomer. So my advice:

```
REPORT:
+----+-----------------+------+-------------+
| ID | Content         |state |Coustomer_ID |
+----+-----------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | I am a content  |  ok  |      1      |
|  1 | I am a content  |  ok  |      1      |
+----+----------+------+------+-------------+
```

With this extra column you could connect your tables with an WHERE statment:

```
WHERE COUSTOMER.ID = REPORT.COUSTOMER_ID
```

or with a JOIN statment

```
COUSTOMER INNER JOIN REPORT ON COUSTOMER.ID = REPORT.COUSTOMER_ID
```

Please note that there are diffenrent way to join tables. [See here for a little explantion](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Now your ready to get your Data:

```
SELECT * FROM COUSTOMER WHERE Lastname = 'Ramesh' AND WHERE COUSTOMER.ID = REPORT.COUSTOMER_ID;
```

Or with joins:

```
SELECT * FROM COUSTOMER INNER JOIN REPORT ON COUSTOMER.ID = REPORT.COUSTOMER_ID WHERE COUSTOMER.ID = 1;
```

The output in both cases should look look like that:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----+-----------------+------+-------------+
| ID | Lastname | AGE | ADDRESS   | ID | Content         |state |Coustomer_ID |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----+-----------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  1 | I am a content  |  ok  |      1      |
|  2 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  1 | I am a content  |  ok  |      1      |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----+----------+------+------+-------------+
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Yes, thank you. I will read this articles.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.*, b.* from customer a join report b on (a.ID =b.ID)
where a.ID=1
```

Comment: why this was down voted? what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have to add a coulom with a Coustomer-ID to the REPORT-table so your able to connect those two tabels. After doing that you could search the coustomer by Name:

```
SELECT * FROM COUSTOMER WHERE Lastname = Ramesh AND WHERE COUSTOMER.ID = REPORT.COUSTOMER_ID;
```

or by his ID:

```
SELECT * FROM COUSTOMER WHERE COUSTOMER.ID = 1 AND WHERE COUSTOMER.ID = REPORT.COUSTOMER_ID;
```

Comment: @Strawberry What do you mean? Could you be a bit more speciffic?

Comment: There are 8 mistakes in your query - well, 8.5 - so it's hard to know where to begin, other than to say that this is not SQL syntax (4 of the mistakes)